# Dense_Rank() alternative in sql server 2000?(Set based)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, dense-rank

Actually, I have the task of finding the employees based on the salary rank.

So I used Dense_Rank() and got the answer.

Initially I was told to solve in SQL SERVER 2005.

Later on they changed the requirement and is saying that the query should run in SQL SERVER 2000 also.

I solved that using a while loop.

But they are saying that they will accept the solution using SET BASED approach.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some details - what are the columns (incl datatype) of the `EMPLOYEES` table?  What was your solution that used a WHILE loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to this article, [Ranking In SQL Server 2000](http://sqlservercode.blogspot.com/2006/03/ranking-in-sql-server-2000.html)

The author talks about how to implement `Dense_Rank()`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
SELECT  * ,
    ( SELECT    COUNT(C1)
      FROM      T1 
      WHERE     P1.C1>= T.C
    ) AS Rnk
FROM    T
ORDER BY C DESC;
```