# ROW_NUMBER() & RANK() - 2nd highest no of leaves- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, row-number

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH0Z8.png

I need help to write a SQL query to print the names of the employees that took the second-highest leaves.

So I need to get the 2nd highest no of leaves (vacation leaves + sick leaves) from the `HumanResources.Employee` table using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()` in the SQL Server `Adventureworks2019` sample database.

Thanks for your time.

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    S.BusinessEntityID, LEAVES,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAVES  ORDER BY LEAVES) AS RN
FROM
    (SELECT 
         BusinessEntityID, 
         (VacationHours + SickLeaveHours) AS LEAVES
     FROM      
         [HumanResources].[Employee]) S
GROUP BY 
    LEAVES, S.BusinessEntityID 
ORDER BY 
    LEAVES DESC
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH0Z8.png

Comment: And, what is the problem with the current query?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results as formatted text.

Comment: don't use `partition by` in `row_number` . Use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LEAVES) AS RN` otherwise you will get the 2nd employee having each number of days of leave when ordered by the length leave so all rows will have a value of 1 for `RN`

Comment: Did the suggestion solve the problem? If not please post information as text.

Comment: @Kendle, No. If I remove PARTITION BY in ROW_NUMBER() Changed the RN as for LEAVES 168-288,289,290 &  for LEAVES 167-285,286,287 ,... so on. I have attached output as image, please verify

Comment: @Kaylan - Posting images (instead of text) limits the help others can offer. For example, I'd like to help but don't have the AdventureWorks db installed, and the one at dbfiddle is currently down, so there's not much I can do but look ;-) To make it easier for others to help you, please post the sample data AND the expected results *as text*.

Comment: My guess would be to try `DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Leave)` instead of ROW_NUMBER(), and grab rows with a rank = 2

Answer (score 0):

Second highest...

```
select * from (
SELECT 
   S.BusinessEntityID, 
   LEAVES,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEAVES  ORDER BY LEAVES) AS RN,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER By LEAVES DESC) as DR
FROM(
      SELECT 
         BusinessEntityID, 
         (VacationHours+SickLeaveHours) AS LEAVES
      FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]      
    ) S
GROUP BY LEAVES, S.BusinessEntityID 
) x where x.DR=2
```

output:

| BusinessEntityID | LEAVES | RN | DR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 116 | 167 | 1 | 2 |
| 124 | 167 | 2 | 2 |
| 92 | 167 | 3 | 2 |

Comment: Can't we do with out using DENSE_RANK( ) and only by using ROW_NUMBER( ). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `DENSE_RANK()` ?

Comment: When you do not want to use `DENSE_RANK()`, you can always emulate it, see: [Dense_Rank() alternative in sql server 2000?(Set based)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592294/dense-rank-alternative-in-sql-server-2000set-based)